# cannot convert type vector3 to float

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to instantiate "sphere" at a position [AU] multiplied by some numbers away from another object which I have defined but it gives me this error:

[image]

Comment: You should edit your code, as text, into your question.

Comment: Please add code and errors as **text** ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors in text format are much, *much* better than code/errors as an image, which are somewhat better than nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error.

Comment: gotcha for now the issue was solved but if at any time i need to make a post again i will hopefuly remember to use this

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to send a vector3 within another vector3 as an x value, you should send the whole variable "spawndistance" and replace it with the new vector3 (...), and it will work in the same way you are using random values in 2 places will be the same.

Comment: A code example, rather than just a description, is a much more understandable way for other people seeking answers.

Comment: the picture is inside the description X D click on the description [first time i post here lately so i managed to somehow implement the picture inside of the description]